# Asymptotics for the number of $n\le x$ which can be written as the sum of two squares. Is Perron's formula applicable?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

For all $n\ge 1$, let
$$
a_n = \begin{cases}
1\quad&\text{if $n$ can be written as the sum of two squares;}\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
**I am interested in $A(x):=\sum_{n\le x}a_n$.**

Consider the $L$-function $F(s)=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{a_n}{n^s}$. We see that $F$ converges absolutely for $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$. Moreover, let $\chi$ be the non-trivial character modulo $4$, then
$$
F(s)^2 = L(\chi,s)\zeta(s)(1-2^{-2s})^{-1}\prod_{p\equiv 3\pmod 4}(1-p^{-2s})^{-1} =: L(\chi,s)\zeta(s)f(s)^2,
$$
so $F(s)^2$ has a meromorphic continuation to $\{s\in\mathbb{C}:\operatorname{Re}(s)>1/2\}$, with a simple pole at $s=1$.

Now, Exercise $6.21(d)$ in Montgomery and Vaughan, which **I need help with**, is to show
$$
A(x) = \frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\mathcal{C}}f(s)\sqrt{\zeta(s)L(\chi s)}\frac{x^s}{s}\,ds + O\left(x\exp\left(-c\sqrt{\log x}\right)\right),
$$
where $\mathcal{C}$ is the contour from $1-c-i\delta$ in a straight line to $1-i\delta$, along the semi-circle $1+\delta e^{i\theta}$ for $-\pi/2\le \theta\le \pi/2$ to $1+i\delta$, and from there to $1-c+i\delta$, where $\delta = 1/\log x$ and $\delta$ is sufficiently small.

---

My first, and thus far only, idea was to consider the closed contour $\mathcal{C}'$, which is $\mathcal{C}$ together with the line segment from $1-c+i\delta$ to $1-c-i\delta$, and to compute
$$
\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{\mathcal{C}'}f(s)\sqrt{\zeta(s)L(\chi s)}\frac{x^s}{s}\,ds
$$
using the residue formula, and to relate $A(x)$ to
$$
\int_{1-c-i\delta}^{1-c+i\delta}f(s)\sqrt{\zeta(s)L(\chi s)}\frac{x^s}{s}\,ds
$$
using Perron's formula.

However, I don't think I can apply the residue theorem to the contour integral around $\mathcal{C}'$, since $f(s)\sqrt{\zeta(s) L(\chi,s)}$ is nowhere near holomorphic around $s=1$ (the square of this function has a pole of order $1$ at $s=1$). And I don't think I can apply Perron's formula because $1-c<1=\sigma_c(F)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still can use Perron's formula, but Hankel contour has to be used instead of closed rectangles because the the function in question is only one-valued in a cut plane. The resulting formula is

$$
A(x)\sim{Kx\over\sqrt{\log x}}\left(1+{b_1\over\log x}+{b_2\over\log^2x}+{b_3\over\log^3x}+\dots\right),
$$

where the right hand side is an asymptotic series. I have written a detailed proof of this result in this [blog article](https://travorlzh.github.io/2022/09/23/number-of-integers-that-are-sum-of-two-squares.html).

Comment: A decade ago I did some numerics and got $b_1 = 0.5819486593172907979281498\ldots$ and $b_2=1.2909972064035629061229292\ldots$.